# Netezza - relation does not exist on SQL select

Tags: sql, netezza

I can't understand why this query wont work, I'm using Netezza DB, new to that. If I remove these two lines:

```
  inner join table_two tb2 
  on tb2.ID = tb1.ID
```

the select works, but it isn't the right result, why is it failing when I use the "inner join" lines? Aynone, please. Thank you!

```
 select  count(t1.FIRSTNAME)
 from  table_one tb1
 inner join table_two tb2 
 on tb2.ID = tb1.ID
 where UPPER(tb1.FIRSTNAME) LIKE 'JOE%' AND UPPER(tb1.LASTNAME) LIKE '%DOE%'
```

Comment: Table structure probably.

Comment: Your misunderstanding either of how joins work or what the data contains.

Comment: The title of your question implies that you are getting an error about a relation/table not existing, but you don't show us the specific error output in the question.  Your sample seems to have an obvious error in that the COUNT refers to T1, but there's no T1 in the rest of the statement. Please update your question with the actual error text.